# File upload via related list not working in IE11

Tags: visualforce-component, attachment, upload

at the moment I'm facing a really weird issue:
I have a custom VF page, that embeds 
    `<apex:relatedList list="CombinedAttachments"/>`

and also a custom VF component.

The uploading of files works fine in all browser, except IE11. In IE11 you can select a file from your harddrive but the upload never starts and the page does not response to any actions.

Debugging the issue, I found that an exception is thrown in the Chatter.js in these lines

```
submitXhr: function(a, c) {
  var d = this, 
  b = new XMLHttpRequest, 
  e = this.filesToUpload[a].fileInfo.name;
  b.upload.onprogress = function(b) {
  if (b.lengthComputable)
    d.config.onProgressCallback(a, e, b.loaded, b.total)
  };
```

To be more precise,

```
b.upload.onprogress
```

throws an exception because b.upload is undefined.

I investigated this further and found the following:

The issue is caused by an 
    `<apex:commandButton>`
in the VF component. As soon as you have a commandButton in your component, b.upload is undefined.

Has anyone experienced something similiar or has an explanation why

```
var b = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

results in b.upload == undefined in some case?

Patrik

Comment: Could be an issue with readAsBinaryString which is not supported in IE. I had the same issue and then used readAsArrayBuffer but I was uploading using connection.js and apex.js.

Comment: After contacting the Salesforce support it turned out that this is a known issue and will be fixed in the Winter '19 release. Check this link for more details:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BmZQAU

Comment: You can post this as the answer so others can be benifitted.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the Salesforce support it turned out that this is a known issue and will be fixed in the Winter '19 release. Check this link for more details: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BmZQAU